# Printing components of structure gives weird repetitions

Tags: c

Im trying to print out the elements in the structure (.WAV file header). I've implemented the endian correction functions. However, when I do printf, it shows a weird repetition of elements. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "prog9.h"

/*
 * little_endian_2 - reads 2 bytes of little endian and reorganizes it into big endian
 * INPUTS:       fptr - pointer to the wav file
 * OUTPUTS:      none
 * RETURNS:      the data that is converted to big endian
 */
int little_endian_2(FILE *fptr)
{
    int count;
    char temp[2];

    fscanf (fptr, "%2c",temp);


    char holder;

    holder = temp[1];
    temp[1] = temp[0];
    temp[0] = holder;

    count = atoi(temp);
    return count;
}

/*
 * little_endian_4 - reads 4 bytes of little endian and reorganizes it into big endian
 * INPUTS:       fptr - pointer to the wav file
 * OUTPUTS:      none
 * RETURNS:      the data that is converted to big endian
 */
int little_endian_4(FILE *fptr)
{
    char temp[4];

    fscanf (fptr, "%4c", temp);

    int final = *(int *)temp;

    //printf ("%i\n",final);

    return final;
}

/*
 * read_file  - read the wav file and fill out the wav file struct
 * INPUTS:      wavfile - a string that contains the name of the file
 * OUTPUTS:     none
 * RETURNS:     the pointer to the wav file struct created in this function
 * SIDE EFFECT: prints the information stored in the wav struct
 */
WAV *read_file(char *wavfile)
{
    WAV* wav_ptr = (WAV*)malloc(sizeof(WAV));

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(wavfile,"r");

    fscanf (fp, "%4c", wav_ptr->RIFF); //For RIFF

    wav_ptr->ChunkSize = little_endian_4(fp);

    fscanf (fp, "%4c", wav_ptr->WAVE); //For WAVE

    fscanf (fp, "%4c", wav_ptr->fmt); //For fmt

    printf("%s\n", wav_ptr->RIFF);
    printf("%i \n", wav_ptr->ChunkSize);
    printf("%s \n", wav_ptr->WAVE);
    printf("%s \n", wav_ptr->fmt);
    return wav_ptr;

}
```

After running this, it prints this to the output.

```
RIFFvu
882038 
WAVEfmt  
fmt
```

The struct looks like this:
    struct wav_t{
        char                RIFF[4];
        int                 ChunkSize;
        char                WAVE[4];
        char                fmt[4];
    };

Comment: You didn't post the definition of `struct WAV` and don't cast `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printf()` calls are printing strings. But your `fscanf()` calls are reading `char`s, which are not-null terminated and hence are not strings.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I posted that before seeing the update to include the wav struct. Incorrectly assumed the buffer was larger. But the key point is correct - trying to print a string with a char array.

Answer (score 0):

The `*printf()` functions with the `"%s"` specifier expect a string which in c requires a terminating `'\0'` byte, that your arrays don't have.

You can do this

```
fwrite(wav_ptr->RIFF, 1, 4, stdout);
fprintf(stdout, "\n");
```

instead, and then you will print the exact number of characters you want to print, that will not force you to modify the data.

Comment: Thanks it worked! So now if I wanted to print out all of the elements of the WAV struct, would I have to write both lines for each element of the struct?

Comment: Well if the contents are not strings, you could write a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%s", ...)` wants to print NUL terminated strings, but your strings aren't NUL terminated.  You can use an explicit maximum length to limit the size and avoid the need for a NUL terminator:

```
printf("%.4s\n", wav_ptr->RIFF);
printf("%i \n", wav_ptr->ChunkSize);
printf("%.4s \n", wav_ptr->WAVE);
printf("%.4s \n", wav_ptr->fmt);
```